# PHP taking variable from a class to another page

Tags: php, oop

i am a newbie at php oop.So I have a problem.

I have a user class, I want to control if there is a member with this ID or nickname.But the page that i want the control if user exists, I cant reach the $query.

this is my Staff class php file

```
 public static function info($id = null, $nick = null){

    if($id){
        $query  =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE yetkili_id = '$id' ");
    }elseif($nick) {
        $query =    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE yetkili_nick = '$nick'");
    }
        if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
            return $query;
        }
}
```

and this is the page that i want to take info of user

```
<?php
Staff::info(1);
$row    =   mysql_fetch_array($query);
print_r($row);
```

?>

and I get this error

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\AppServ\www\oneriyor\admin\login.php on line 3
```

I dont know what is the solution.If you can help me guys i will be appreciate.

Comment: learn about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). you may want  use `$query = Staff::info(1);`

Comment: Please start using `mysqli_*` (OOP) as classes are OOP or `PDO` becasue `mysql_*` is deprecated and will be removed

Comment: Oh thank you. I know what is variable scope, but I didn't know how could I get it in the OOP.
By the way, what is your suggestion? Using mysqli_ or PDO?

Comment: @M.Beefy becasue I susupect you're used to `mysql_*` from looking at your code. I would suggest `mysqli_*` because there a just some small differences. But if you would like to go full OOP including `mysqli_*` I would suggest you start watching some tutorials. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpOIUW62tnJTtpWFABxWZ8g The older tutorials are the easiest to begin with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @frederico says, you have a variable scope misunderstanding.

Your $query is *inside* your function. So you can use it only inside. Try to move your "fetch" inside your function instead of your return. And follow the @frederico's link !